# How to add elements or nodes, to existing XML, given an input string to compare with - using a LINQ query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am looking for a solution using a 1-stmt LINQ query instead. 
I have an input string that is technically the person's name, if this  is not already in the XML given, I need to update the XML with this  added.

I'm able to query 2 XMLs easily, but not XML and this name-string (it looks at it character-wise, not as a whole string). Maybe some kind of conversion may help? I could also wrap this string into an XML if it makes the query simpler to write.

Here is the approach to explain what I desire to achieve in the LINQ query, without using the messy foreach/ifs like below: 
XML1:

```
        /*      <classes>
         *          <set>
         *              <name>Students</name>
         *                  <Person>
         *                          <PID>1</PID>
         *                          <Val>Jack</Val>
         *                      </Person>
         *                      <Person>
         *                          <PID>2</PID>
         *                          <Val>Jill</Val>
                                </Person>
         *                  </set>
         *                </classes>
         */
    XDocument listOfChild = XDocument.Parse("<aboveXML/>");
    string ipString = "Value2";
    bool childExists = false;
    XElement addChild = null;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipString))
    {

        foreach (var tag in listOfChild.Descendants("Person"))
            if (tag.Element("Val").Value.ToLower() == ipString.ToLower()) 
            {
                childExists = true;
                break;
            }

        if (!childExists)
        {
            addChild = new XElement("Person",
                                 new XElement("PID", -1),
                                 new XElement("Val", ipString)
                                     );
        }
    }
    XElement el1 = listOfChild.Root.Descendants("set").FirstOrDefault(); 
    el1.Add(addChild);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
listOfChild.Root.Descendants( "set" ).FirstOrDefault().Add(
    listOfChild.Descendants( "Val" ).Where( v => v.Value.ToLower() == ipString.ToLower() ).
                                     Select( v => ( XElement ) null ).
                                     DefaultIfEmpty( new XElement("Person",
                                                     new XElement( "PID", -1 ),
                                                     new XElement( "Val", ipString ) ) ).
                                     First() );
```

Comment: Thank you. I found where to put the 'where' condition very complicated. Am still very new to LINQ, but want to be really familiar with it. Do you know of any good sites/books for learning LINQ extensively, in addition to practical usage?

Comment: I now a couple of good books for LINQ learning: [`Pro LINQ: Language Integrated Query in C# 2010`](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430226536) by `Apress` and [`Programming Microsoft LINQ in Microsoft .NET Framework 4`](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0790145300461) by `O'Reilly`.

Comment: And of course you can find interesting information in MSDN: [`LINQ to XML Overview in MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb308960.aspx), [`LINQ MSDN Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594)